# Making a dropdown in Bootstrap Select

Tags: jquery, html, select, bootstrap-select

Im trying to show my options in a group but I want it would be something like a dropdown menu, for example we have

- option 1
- option 2
- option 3

when user clicked on option 2 a dropdown menu opens and it contains

- sub_option 1
- sub_option 2
- sub_option 3

is there any way I could do this with bootstrap select?
if not , can you suggest me a way to do that ?!

tnx every body

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: As a menu you mean ?

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Rank').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="1" id="Rank" title="" name="Rank">
    <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="airman">Airman</option>
    <option value="senior-airman">Senior Airman</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
    <div class="airman">
        Line of text for Airman
    </div>
    <div class="senior-airman">
        Line of text for Senior Airman
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="airman">
        <select>
            <option>Airman Stuff</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="senior-airman">
        <select>
            <option>Senior Airman Stuff</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```